# Tesseract: RetriveResultDetail-Method always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, ocr, tesseract

I want to do an OCR with the Tesseract OCR-Engine in .Net. Therefore I use the tesseractdotnet-Wrapper [1](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/wiki/TesseractEngineWrapper). I need to get the word position of each recognized word (RetriveResultDetail-Method):

```
TesseractProcessor ocr = new TesseractProcessor();
ocr.Init(executionPath, "eng", 3);
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
Console.WriteLine(ocr.Apply(image));
List<tesseract.Word> wordList = ocr.RetriveResultDetail();
```

Unfortunately the wordList is always `null` although the Apply-Method shows text results at the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I while researching I found out that I have to invoke the `Apply-method` before calling the `RetriveResultDetail-method`. After invoking the `Apply-method` the word list is not empty anyomre. The code would look like that:

```
TesseractProcessor ocr = new TesseractProcessor();
ocr.Init(executionPath, "eng", 3);
string result = ocr.Apply(bmp);
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
Console.WriteLine(ocr.Apply(image));
List<tesseract.Word> wordList = ocr.RetriveResultDetail();
```

Answer (score 0):

The RetriveResultDetail() always returns a list of words which are string of **numbers** even though the image contains only **alphabets**